How to Simulate a Failed Subscription Renewal Payment in Stripe?
I need to test the backend behavior when a subscription renewal payment fails in Stripe.
What have I tried so far?

I used our UI to go through the checkout process and successfully paid for a subscription in test mode (both the customer and subscription were created).
Then I deleted the customer’s payment card and added a new one using a test card from Stripe’s documentation meant to simulate a declined payment (card number: 4000 0000 0000 0341).
Finally, I ran the simulation and moved the subscription one month forward, as our subscription is set to renew monthly.

As a result, I received the invoice.payment_failed event, but I did not receive the payment_intent.payment_failed event as I expected.
Why did I only receive the invoice.payment_failed event and not the payment_intent.payment_failed event? How can I properly simulate a failed subscription renewal payment?

The invoice.payment_failed is enough to say that the Subscription renewal payment has failed. You can find all the needed Subscription's webhook events and how to handle them following this guide: https://docs.stripe.com/billing/subscriptions/webhooks#payment-failures
